# webservice call, soapaction without namespace

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

I'm developing a wsdl webservice to consume calls from an external device.
The webservice is written in C# with .NET Framework 3.5, we use VS2012.
My problem is that the calls coming from the device, are send with a header without the namespace in the soapaction.

Example call from the device:

```
POST http://10.32.4.138/wscheckbadge/badge.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.32.4.138
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: 300
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 547
SOAPACTION : "heartBeat"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:txn="http://timeAttnHost.mydomain.com"
xmlns:xsd="http://timeAttnHost.mydomain.com/xsd"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body><txn:heartBeat
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><txn:timestamp
xsi:type="xsi:long">1381504799</txn:timestamp><txn:terminalId
xsi:type="xsi:string">PT65-9410</txn:terminalId></txn:heartBeat></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

on this we receive this error:

> "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
>   heartBeat."

In Fiddler I composed the same call but changed the soapaction:

```
SOAPACTION : "http://timeAttnHost.mydomain.com/heartBeat"
```

This passed without errors.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WSCheckBadge
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://timeAttnHost.mydomain.com")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Badge : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private CheckBadge.Badges badges = null;

        [WebMethod]
        public CheckBadge.PayterTxnResponse heartBeat(long timestamp, string terminalid)
        {
            if (badges == null)
                badges = new CheckBadge.Badges(Properties.Settings.Default.XamConnectionString);

            return badges.heartBeat(timestamp, terminalid);
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot change the way the device is making it's calls, otherwise I would add the namespace in the soapaction.

Is there a way to make my webservice consume the call anyway?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use WCF instead of ASMX ? IS your service used by other clients ? You can try to remove WebServiceBinding.

Comment: @RomEh Removing the WebServiceBinding doesn't help. I'll try creating a WCF service.

Comment: You will have more customization possibilities with WCF. You should use a custom binding of your own, with a very basic configuration

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Actually Microsoft products should not be used for new development. we are using PHP and Java over Linux machine for all new developments. You are right, asmx code belongs to a legacy code and we still need to maintain and enhance it until we migrate all of our base code to Linux platforms

Comment: @AaA what do you mean Microsoft technologies shouldn't be used? You mean at your company? Are you in the same company as @MrSigge?